# how can i apply two shipping types?

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shipping-methods

i have this requirement of applying two kind of shipping method. I have obtained the required shipping rates calculation via flat rate and table rate, now i have to let users choose two of the shipping methods. in the picture below those two are the group, from where one from each group needs to be applied.

[image]

I have calculated it as according to the requirements, but i have no idea on how to make it possible to apply one from each of the group ? The functionality is two(each one from the group) of the shipping methods needs to be applied with those prices; any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: This is not possible in magento :(

Comment: @Abdul what could be the other option, how can i create adding fee and apply per item ? (as i want to seperate rush,quick and standard and they apply per item basis)